# Check if a list contains incrementing elements starting from zero

Tags: python

I want to check if a list contains incrementing elements, incremented by one each and starting with 0. So, e.g. `[0, 1, 2, 3]` should return "valid", whereas e.g. `[0, 1, 3, 4]` or `[-1, 0, 1]` should return "not valid".

Is there an easy way to achieve that in Python? Maybe a built-in function?

Comment: I'm currently just check if there exists a 0 in my array `y` and assume it to be filled with increasing values. I'm dealing with classification and the values in the array represent class labels. But using something like `(y == 0).any()` is only ok if the array has the form I'm assuming. But to check it I want to know if there is any function or easy way to do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the problem is truly as you describe it, this can be solved trivially using `range`, like so:

```
myList = [...]
if myList == list(range(myList[-1] + 1)):
    # Do stuff.
```

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase which is exactly as the OP stated it should be.

Comment: @N.Wouda Thank you very much, this solved my problem perfectly! I see that this is actually a trivial question, but I'm a Python beginner and very glad for your solution.

Comment: @PatrickWeiß just because the solution is simple, does not mean the question is bad! You're welcome :).

Comment: Wrapping in list(...) is only necessary in Python 3. It's a list naturally in Python 2

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all) :

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> not l[0] and all(y-x==1 for x,y in zip(l, l[1:]))
True
>>> l1 = [0,1,2,3,5,7]
>>> not l[0] and all(y-x==1 for x,y in zip(l1, l1[1:]))
False
>>> l2 = [0,1,2,3,4,7]
>>> not l[0] and all(y-x==1 for x,y in zip(l2, l2[1:]))
False
>>> l3=[-1,0,1,2]
>>> not l[0] and all(y-x==1 for x,y in zip(l3, l3[1:]))
False
>>> l2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,7]
>>> not l[0] and all(y-x==1 for x,y in zip(l2, l2[1:]))
False
>>> l4=[0,2,3,4,5,7,8]
>>> not l[0] and all(y-x==1 for x,y in zip(l4, l4[1:]))
False
>>> l5=[0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> not l[0] and all(y-x==1 for x,y in zip(l5, l5[1:]))
False
```

So you can put this into a function, this way:

```
def check_my_list(lst):
    if not lst:
        print 'List Empty'
        return False
    test = not lst[0] and all(y-x==1 for x,y in zip(lst,lst[1:])
    return test
```

Comment: Shouldn't `[-1, 0, 1, 2]` evaluate to `False`, as per the OP's guidelines?

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be solved via a one-liner in a functional manner:

```
print not len(filter(lambda i: i!=-1, [x[i]-x[i+1] for i in range(len(x)-1)]))
```

given `True` for `x = [0, 1, 2, 3]` and `False` for `x = [0, 1, 3, 4]`

Explanation:

```
 [x[i]-x[i+1] for i in range(len(x)-1)]
```

makes a list of differences between successive elements, obviously we want to have all `-1`...

Then we use `filter` to select those elements which are different from `-1`, if there is at least one, it is not a incrementing elements and so the length of such filtered list > 0

If yes, i.e. there are just `-1`, the field is empty and we get length of 0.

Comment: Love the `lambda` approach, but shouldn't `[-1, 0, 1, 2]` evaluate to `False`, as per the OP's guidelines?

Comment: @n-wouda yes, that's true, I did not see it before, thanks:) so maybe we can add `abs()` to the expression like that: `abs(x[i])-abs(x[i+1])`