# How to check if a list contains integers incrementing by one

Tags: python, list

I need a function that receives a list and sees if the next element is the sum of the previous plus 1 like this `[x, x+1, (x+1)+1]` if so gives `True`

An example would be:

```
[1,2,3] ------- True
[38,39,40]----- True
[99,100,101]--- True
[30,31,35]----- False
[1,2,2]-------- False
```

Comment: Related: [Check if a list contains incrementing elements starting from zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34684461/7851470)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one line:

```py
my_list == list(range(my_list[0], my_list[0] + len(my_list)))
```

But this probably isn't the most readable.

As a function

```py
def is_incremental(my_l):
   return my_l == list(range(my_l[0], my_l[0] + len(my_l)))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def func(lis):
    res= [False]
    for i in range(1,len(lis)+1):
        if lis[i]==lis[i-1]+1:
            res.append(True)
        else:
            res.append(False)
    return res
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something along these lines:

```
cases=[
[1,2,3],
[38,39,40],
[99,100,101],
[30,31, 35],
[1,2,2]]

for case in cases:
    print(case, all(a+1==b for a,b in zip(case,case[1:])))
```

prints:

```
[1, 2, 3] True
[38, 39, 40] True
[99, 100, 101] True
[30, 31, 35] False
[1, 2, 2] False
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in range(1,len(list)):
     if list[i] != list[i-1]+1:
             return False
return True
```